# Shaitani waswasa and makroohat of ghusl

Tags: ghusl

I have the problem of shaitanic waswasas I keep on cleaning bathing doing wudu continuosly. Today when with all courage i was able to finish Ghusl, I accidentally called someone to close the tap which was outside . Talking from bathroom is considered makrooh act . Is my ghusl valid if I was performing fard ghusl

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. "Talking from bathroom is considered makrooh act " By whom? And why shoulod your ghusl be invalid by talking? Note that it is recommended to do some du'a's while performing wudu'.

Answer (score 1):

> "Talking in the toilet
>
> Answer: In the name of Allah, the most Beneficent, the most Merciful.
>
> It is **against adab and respect** that one speaks and talks whilst in
>   the toilet. One should refrain from crying and doing these kinds of
>   these things inside the toilet.
>
> Only Allah Knows Best
>
> Mohammed Tosir Miah
>
> Darul Ifta Birmingham"
>   (https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/87484)
>
> "Moreover, the majority of scholars say that it is **makruh**
>   (disliked) to, **unnecessarily**, speak in the bathroom/**toilet**."
>   (http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/common-mistakes/using-cell-phone-in-bathroom-allowed/)

So from the aforementioned things, it is clear that ** TALKING UNNECESSARILY is makruh.** In your case, talking (whether unnecessary or necessary) won't affect your GHUSL.

> Speaking during ghusl is somewhat disliked (makruh tanzihan), but
>   **doesn’t affect the validity of the ghusl itself in any ways.** (https://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/43454)

Secondly, you used the term "accidentally", which shows that you talked without intention. Doing something unintentionally **won't make you punishable or won't invalid things (e.g. fast, ghusl, wudu).**

> At the same time, Allaah says that there is no sin on one who is
>   ignorant, forgetful or makes a mistake.
>
> Allaah describes the believers as saying (interpretation of the
>   meaning):
>
> “ ‘Our Lord! Punish us not if we forget or fall into
>   error’”[al-Baqarah 2:286]
>
> According to a report narrated by Muslim from the hadeeth of Abu
>   Hurayrah (125), Allaah said. “Yes”; according to another report from
>   the hadeeth of Ibn ‘Abbaas (126), Allaah said, “I have done that”
>   (i.e., responded to the prayer uttered in this aayah).
>   (https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10686/there-is-no-sin-on-a-person-who-drops-the-mus-haf-unintentionally)